# Parsing multiple xml files in python and appending the data to a Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe

I'm trying to create a data frame from multiple nested xml files and append the data to a single data frame. I know the structure of the data frame and have defined it.

```
tree_list = []
details = ['FirstName','LastName','City','Country','InceptionYear']


for file in bucket_list:
    obj = s3.Object(s3_bucket_name,file)
    data = (obj.get()['Body'].read())
    tree_list.append(ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(data)))

def parse_XML(list_of_trees, df_cols): 
    
    for tree in tree_list:
        xroot = tree.getroot()
        rows = []
    
    
    
    for node in xroot: 
        res = []
        for el in df_cols[0:]: 
            if node is not None and node.find(el) is not None:
                res.append(node.find(el).text)
            else: 
                res.append(None)
        rows.append({df_cols[i-1]: res[i-1] 
                     for i, _ in enumerate(df_cols)})
    
    out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df_cols)
        
    return out_df

parse_XML(tree_list,details)
```

In my output data frame, I'm getting the information of the last file read and a couple of blank rows like the following:

```
    FirstName LastName    City     Country
    Ted       Mosbey      Washington  USA
    None      None        None       None
    None      None        None       None
```

What changes should be made in the code to read all the files, append to the data frame and remove the unnecessary rows? Any suggestion to process the files efficiently is appreciated.

XML example:

```
<PD>
  <Clt>
    <PType>xxxx</PType>
    <PNumber>xxxxx</PNumber>
    <UID>xxxx</UID>
    <TEfd>xxxxx</TEfd>
    <TExd>xxxxxx</TExd>
    <DID>xxxxx</DID>
    <CType>xxxxx</CType>
    <FName>John</FName>
    <MName></MName>
    <LName>Smith</LName>
    <MAL>Home</MAL>
    <AddressLine1>xxxx</AddressLine1>
    <AddressLine2>xxxx</AddressLine2>
    <AddressLine3></AddressLine3>
    <City>xxxx</City>
    <State>xx</State>
    <ZipCode>xxxx</ZipCode>
    <Country>xxxx</Country>
    <Pr>
      <PrType>xxxxx</PrType>
      <PrName>xxxxxx</PrName>
      <PrID>xxxxxx</PrID>
    </Pr>
</Clt>
  <CData>
    <InceptionYear>2021</InceptionYear>
  </CData>
</PD>
```

Comment: Code reference - https://medium.com/@robertopreste/from-xml-to-pandas-dataframes-9292980b1c1c

Edited as per requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So now when I have your data sample, I tested this and it works for me just as I think you want it to be:

```
def parse_XML(list_of_trees, df_cols):

    def get_el(el_list):
        if len(el_list) > 1:
            return [el_text.text for el_text in el_list]
        else:
            return el_list[0].text
    rows = []
    for tree in list_of_trees:
        xroot = tree.getroot()

        res = {}
        for node in xroot:
            for el in df_cols[0:]:
                if node is not None and node.find(f".//{el}") is not None:
                    el_res = get_el(node.findall(f".//{el}"))
                    if el not in res:
                        res[el] = el_res
                    elif type(res[el]) == list:
                        res[el].extend(el_res)
                    else:
                        res[el] = [res[el], el_res]
        rows.append(res)

    out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df_cols)

    return out_df
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get this error if i remove res.append(None) -  the IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Yes, I can see it (now), I've updated my answer and I've updated the row without re-looping.

Comment: Got this error after the changes - TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I convinced I can't answer it without data to test it first :(

Comment: res.append(node.find(el).text) worked but I'm still getting the extra rows with None and '\n\t'. For 5 files, instead of 5 rows I'm getting 19

Comment: No matter what I've tried, I failed to reproduce this error. I've created three files and two of them with empty tags and I'm getting three rows with None for the empty tags columns in two of the rows.

Comment: I had to add out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df_cols).replace(to_replace='None', value=np.nan).dropna()
    out_df = out_df.reset_index(drop=True)
to make the stuff work. Not sure if it is a file or spacing one

Comment: Can you make the changes to fit the sub-nested tags as well? PrType in this case

Comment: I've updated my answer to search for tags recursively. You just have to add the tags to the details list.

Comment: How can we adjust the code to accommodate more sub nested tags or more complexed sub-nests?

Comment: As long as the tags are unique this function should do. If you expected repeated tags, then it would be good practice to use the findall method (instead of find), which will return a list of values, inside an inner function that will return the value or list of values.

Comment: I got this error when I added a tag outside of <clt> in this sample xml. 
ValueError: 20 columns passed, passed data had 19 columns
I tried findall as well but that gave me an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: I've updated my answer to handle repeated tags. I'm not sure about your meaning of adding a tag outside of <clt>

Comment: The updated code gives out an error - IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I find it hard to imagine every possible form of data, If you can hand me the data I might help you more.

Comment: I've updated the xml and example in the details list. More tags in different nests could be added but the structure will remain extremely nested.

Comment: I've updated my answer. My assumption is that data holds one customer's details per XML file. Repeated tags will be grouped in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**`pandas.read_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) introduced in Pandas v1.3.0 where you parse at two different levels in XML and join them together.

```py
def build_frame(dom): 
    xml_df = (
        pd.read_xml(txt, xpath=".//Clt", parser="etree")
          .reindex(["FirstName", "LastName", "City", "Country"], axis="columns")
          .join(
              pd.read_xml(txt, xpath=".//CData", parser="etree")[['InceptionYear']]
          )
    )
    return xml_df

# BUILD LIST OF PARSED XML DATA FRAMES
df_list = []
for file in bucket_list:
    obj = s3.Object(s3_bucket_name,file)
    data = (obj.get()['Body'].read())
    df_list.append(build_frame(data))

# ALTERNATIVE: BUILD LIST VIA COMPREHENSION
df_list = [
    build_frame(s3.Object(s3_bucket_name, file).get()['Body'].read()))
    for file in bucket_list
]

# COMBINE DATA FRAMES INTO SINGLE MASTER DATA FRAME
master_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

---

Above uses the non-default, `etree` parser. But if you have `lxml` installed (the third-party package for full support of XPath 1.0 and XSLT 1.0), you can make one `read_xml` call (combining XPath expressions) with some data frame cleanup:

```py
cols = ["FirstName", "LastName", "City", "Country", "InceptionYear"]

def build_frame(dom): 
    xml_df = (
        pd.read_xml(txt, xpath=".//Clt|.//CData", parser="lxml")
          .assign(InceptionYear = lambda x: x["InceptionYear".bfill)  # BACKWARD FILL COLUMN
          .reindex(cols, axis="columns")                              # FILTER COLUMNS
          .query("LastName == LastName")                              # FILTER ROWS (REMOVE NaNs)
    )
    return xml_df
```